# How can I save a webpage as an image in my rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app I have a need to save some webpages and display them to the user as images. For example, how would I save www.google.com as an image?

Answer (score 7):

There is a command line utility called CutyCapt that is using the WebKit-Rendering engine to render HTML-Pages into various image formats. Maybe this is for you? 
http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Snazzy! Janak, you'll still want to use this as a background task, but I think this will probably be a better fit for you than an external service.

Answer (score 1):

Prohibitively difficult to do in pure Ruby, so you'd want to use an external service for this. [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) does it, for example, and it looks like they have an [api](http://api.browsershots.org/xmlrpc/), although I haven't used it myself. Maybe someone else can chime in with alternative but similar services.

You'll also want to [read](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/11/19/delayed-gratification-with-rails/) [up](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/4/14/building_a_queuebacked_feed_reader_part_1/) on delayed_job or something similar, to make sure you're accessing those page images as a background task and that it doesn't interfere with your actual application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it easily (probably can't do it at all).
Each page is just a text - html data. The view you want to make an image of is a rendered page. Browser renders the page using tonns of techniques like html parsing, javascript parsing, css parsing, font rendering, etc.. To make the screenshot of google page - you would need to do all the rendering somewhere in memory and then take a screenshot of rendered page.

That task is almost impossible (there is nothing fully impossible).
If you are really eager to donate tonns of time to accomplish that task - you should do this steps:
1) Find some opensource rendering engine. Firefox would do.
2) Find some way to communicate between ruby-on-rails and that engine.
3) Wire it all together and see the results.

However, I see steps 1 and 2 as nearly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/